# Ansible: how to import GPG private key from file?

Tags: ansible, gnupg

Manually, to import a GPG private key:

```
gpg --import myprivatekey.key
```

How can I do this using Ansible on a remote machine? Suppose the private key resides as a file on my local machine, how can I import the private key on a remote machine using Ansible?

I've searched the documentation, but Ansible does not seem to have a module for this task.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Ansible gpg module. You'll have to provide the passphrase on the command line. Use [vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) or any other encryption system to encrypt the variable with the passphrase. For example,

```yaml
- name: Import gpg private key
  command: >
    gpg --batch
        --passphrase {{ gpg_passphrase }} 
        --pinentry-mode loopback
        --import private.key
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

Comment: Does not answer the question

Comment: I've improved the answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by using the `--pinentry-mode` option in conjunction with the `--passphrase` or `--passphrase-file` options.

For example:

```sh
gpg --passphrase-file passphrase.txt --pinentry-mode loopback --import private.key
```